# How to remove all consecutive numbers in select statement?

Tags: sql, sql-server

If I had a SQL Server query that returns numbers in order like this

```
1
2
3
5
6
7
9
10
11
```

how can I remove numbers such that no two adjacent pairs are consecutive by 1? The above should be returned like

```
3
5
7
9
```

Is this possible to do?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

We can use `LEAD` and `LAG` here:

```sql
WITH cte AS (
    SELECT id, LAG(id) OVER (ORDER BY id) lag_id, LEAD(id) OVER (ORDER BY id) lead_id
    FROM yourTable
)

SELECT id
FROM cte
WHERE lag_id <> id - 1 OR lead_id <> id + 1
ORDER BY id;
```

Comment: Does this still work if the numbers are not ordered from the table? I see you have a `order by id` already. Does this take care of the ordering or do I need to make sure to order it first?

Comment: @omega There is no actual "order" to the values in your table.  You seem to want this logic to apply to the series of numbers in ascending order.  The `ORDER BY` clauses in `LEAD` and `LAG` from my answer make this assumption.

Answer (score 2):

You can try to use `LEAD` and `LAG` window functions and calculation what rows are consecutive by 1.

```
SELECT Val
FROM (
 SELECT *,
       LEAD(Val) OVER(ORDER BY Val) - Val gap1,
       Val - LAG(Val) OVER(ORDER BY Val) gap2
 FROM T 
) t1
WHERE gap1 > 1 OR gap2 > 1
```